# How to get javascript post variable in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small problem to get jQuery post variables. So i have javascript file where is code bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post("view.php", { name: "John" } );
</script>
```

And i try to get that name "John" in view.php file like this:

```
<?php $variable = $_GET["name"]; ?>
```

And it wont get that name. Can someone please help me?

Comment: try $_POST["name"] instead...

Answer (score 5):

The variable values are not included in `$_GET` you might find them in `$_POST`

```
<?php $variable = $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used '$.post' you must use the related action which will be $_POST. If you were using '$.get', then you would use your current method of $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_POST instead of $_GET...

Answer (score 0):

And you can use

```
<?php $variable = $_REQUEST['name']; ?>
```

if not shure how it should be get.